# Is it acceptable to omit "I" when it's the subject?

Tags: grammaticality, british-english, subjects, ellipses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it acceptable to begin a declarative sentence with “Am”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58285/is-it-acceptable-to-begin-a-declarative-sentence-with-am)

Is it correct English to omit *I* from the beginning of a sentence when it's clearly implied?

For example...

> How are you? Hope everything's okay?

as opposed to

> How are you? I hope everything's okay?

Comment: I noticed that I was doing it in an email, started to correct myself and then wondered how wrong it really was. So you'd say it's incorrect but commonplace?

Comment: Interesting - turns out there's a *that* missing, as well: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-marking_in_English

Comment: @Lunivore Good point. That'll teach me not to contrive examples without more thought :) Thanks for the link

Comment: Adding to Lunivore link, I suggest you to read this: [Null-subject languge](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-subject_language). It is really interesting.

Comment: Related [Proper usage of pronouns](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84481/proper-usage-of-pronouns).

Comment: What RegDwighт♦ said. The only difference is that one asks whether it's *grammatical* (no), but this one asks whether it's *acceptable* (for many people - yes, in informal contexts).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Languages in which omitting the subject is gramatically correct are called [null-subject languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-subject_language). English isn't one of them.

The linked Wikipedia article does mention the dropping of a subject in some sentences, but says that this is a colloquialism.